# How to search and update in an XML using JaxB in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm able to create java object from an xml schema and creating a new xml is also working.

Now using my java object how can i search for a particular tag and update it back into xml?

Comment: Go through the basic tutorial on JAXB http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/. If you are stuck at certain point discuss that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an instance of `Marshaller` to write the object back to XML.  If you want to apply changes back to an existing DOM then you can use an instance of `Binder`.  `Binder` is useful when there is unmapped content in your document that you wish to preserve.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html